# Non-ascii characters in "ng build" output

Tags: angular, non-ascii-characters, ng-build

When I run `ng build` I get some non-ASCII characters in the console output:

```
15:02:51 info: Microsoft.AspNetCore.SpaServices[0]
15:02:51       i ï½¢wdsï½£: webpack output is served from /
```

I searched for the string `i ï½¢wdsï½£` and found it in some other places, e.g. https://www.genuitec.com/forums/topic/project-test-a-is-not-an-angular-cli-project/.

Is it something I should be concerned about? The project runs fine otherwise.

Comment: Are you running ng build in a Windows Command Line, Powershell command line, or some sort of bash shell?

Comment: `ï½¢` is what you get when your console tries to display the UTF-8 `｢` [character](https://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/ff62/index.htm) in a code point such as [Windows-1252](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows-1252). `｢` is encoded as `0xEF 0xBD 0xA2` in UTF-8. This becomes the three separate characters you see.  And `ï½£` is UTF-8 `｣`. So overall, it looks to me like it's trying to show you `i ｢wds｣`. No idea if you should be concerned, tho.

Comment: @GeorgeStocker On Jenkins, actually.

Comment: Makes my Jenkins/Docker build outputs really ugly. Is there any command-line option for ng that turns off these non-ASCII characters in progress messages?